# Very long response time from HTTP REST request on Extreme OS switch

Tags: rest, http, cisco

I'm trying to use REST API on Extreme OS to retrieve information on interfaces, PoE etc.... It works perfectly fine with Cisco switches, but now I'm trying the same thing on an Extreme Networks switch. However the delay between my HTTP GET request and the answer is very long (~7 minutes). On Cisco it takes ~15 seconds.

I have used tcpdump, but it doesn't know how to interpret or solve the reset and keep-alive (response start at frame 1302).

[tcpdump capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B8sax.png)

I use the following command to make my HTTP request:

```
curl -k -v http://<ip>/rest/restconf/data/openconfig_interfaces:interfaces/ -u "<user>:<password>"
```